# Idiom for counting other people's money/fortunes

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom or expression for when people are counting other people's fortunes or money. Usually it's a gross over-exaggeration of reality stemming from envy.

Example:  "He can probably afford 5 houses on whatever he's getting paid!"

Example 2: "Look at you.  You must be getting all sorts of dates."

(Edit) 
I'm looking for something to use as a response to such assumptions directed at me or other people. If someone assumes I'm very fortunate at X (when I'm not) I want a response that grounds their assumption. It could be a quote or an idiom. I want something more eloquent than "Careful about counting other people's fortunes" or "People are always better at counting other people's fortunes than their own"

Comment: How do you expect to use this expression? Can you give an example sentence, with `_____` in place of the expression?

Comment: There are any number of metaphors, including those referencing [Croesus](http://www.ancient.eu/croesus/) or maybe [Crassus](http://www.ancient.eu/Marcus_Licinius_Crassus/). Do take a look at the tag info for [single-word-requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and [phrase-requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) for help with this sort of question. Questions can always be brought off-hold once there is sufficient detail.

Comment: I'm looking for something to use as a response to such assumptions directed at me or other people.  If someone assumes I'm very fortunate at X (when I'm not)  I want a response that grounds their assumption.  It could be a quote or an idiom.  I want something more eloquent than "Careful about counting other people's fortunes" or "People are always better at counting other people's fortunes than their own"

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "counting other people's fortunes" - is that native English or a translation of an idiom from another language?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so that may be coming across in the example.  That's the best way I can put it at the moment.

Comment: "Don't cont other people chickens before they've hatched"?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your comment.  "Appearances are deceiving" is a good comeback.

Answer (score 1):

For "Careful about counting other people's fortunes", you should consider: ***The grass is always greener on the other side (of the fence)***.

dictionary.com:

> **[the grass is always greener on the other side of the fence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/the-grass-is-always-greener-on-the-other-side-of-the-fence)**
>   People are never satisfied with their own situation; they always think
>   others have it better.
>
> The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy, Third
>   Edition Copyright © 2005 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Published by
>   Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.

Wiktionary:

> *Proverb*
>   **[the grass is always greener on the other side](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_grass_is_always_greener_on_the_other_side#English)**
>
> Other circumstances seem more desirable than one's own but in reality
>   are often not.